# If Java is a managed language then why do we have to manually close AutoCloseable resources?

Tags: java

In java, is it necessary for me to manually `close` all `AutoCloseable` and `Closeable` objects (whether through explicit call or relying on try-with-resources)?

Does the JVM not automatically clean up `AutoCloseable`s and `Closeable`s when they are no longer being referenced?

Is calling `close` explicitly (whether through explicit call or relying on try-with-resources) a manner of etiquette (i.e., recommended but not necessary) and is the reason to avoid indeterministic resource deallocation which would happen otherwise if one relied on the built in GC?

Comment: GC is not able to release anything other than allocated memory. Resources, however,  are not limited to allocated memory.

Comment: The primary reason is that you close it in a timely fashion (eg finalizer can take a while to run (if ever), and ensure it is closed even if the object itself is long-lived. Or with JDBC + a connection pool: to ensure that the connection is returned to the pool.